# xinput mapping of tablet input device fails 18.04

Tags: xinput, graphics-tablet

I have a tablet screen that I use on 18.04. It behaves essentially like an absolute position mouse (it's a Huion, not a Wacom), but I run with multiple monitors, so I have to apply a transformation matrix to the device.

I wrote a program to calculate the transformation matrix, and it's been working fine with 16.04, but now on 18.04, whenever I try to use it, it fails, complaining of a BadMatch. I recall it doing this while I was creating the program, if the numbers were missing or bad, but since this was previously tested, that doesn't seem reasonable. Here's the command that results from my program, and the resulting error message:

```
~$ xinput set-prop 'Tablet Monitor Pen' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 0.333333 0.000000 0.166667 0.000000 0.486692 0.513308 0 0 1
  X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  21
```

the elements of xrandr that I believe are relevant for the numbers are:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2104, maximum 8192 x 8192
...
DP-1 connected 1280x1024+640+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 760mm x 450mm
```

Can anyone tell me if something changed with the format expected by xinput for this, between 16.04 and 18.04? Or if somehow my numbers are calculated incorrectly and it's only just shown up (I did change the monitor configuration, but not a lot!)

Edit: In further investigation, I notice that even the default/existing CTM is rejected. Requesting the current state looks like this:

```
$ xinput list-props 'Tablet Monitor Pen' | grep "Coordinate Transformation Matrix"
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

And putting those values back (with or without the commas) results in:

```
xinput set-prop 'Tablet Monitor Pen' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  21
```

Doing it with the commas in the data list (which used to not be allowed) results in the same:

```
$ xinput set-prop 'Tablet Monitor Pen' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  21
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear, embarrassingly, it turns out the device name has been changed. My xinput -list output includes:

```
    $ xinput -list
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ 2.4G wireless USB Device 2.4G wireless USB Device id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ Tablet Monitor Pad                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ Tablet Monitor Pen Pen (0)                id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
 Virtual core keyboard                      id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Tablet Monitor Pen                        id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and the relevant device had always been 'Tablet Monitor Pen' in 16.04. However, it's actually the 'Tablet Monitor Pen Pen (0)' that works now. So, given that change in the target device, everything is back to working...

Comment: Oh! Darn! I saw the name under "keyboard" so I was like: that's correct, but that's the one under "pointer" you have to use. That was a nice hint. Also my monitor name changed from `"DVI-I-0"` (zero) to `"DVI-I-1"` (one).